# How to solve infinity norm minimization problem in matlab?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, matlab

My optimization problem looks like following: (I have to solve for diagonal matrix D when A and B are given.)
$$\mbox{minimize}  \quad \|BDB^{T} - A\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: $x=A^{-1}b$ but maybe you have some constraint on $x$?

Comment: @Paul  A may not be invertible, and quite likely is not even square.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I have change the CVX code because the problem statement has been changed.  Here is the new code.

This is easy to do in CVX http://cvxr.com/cvx/ under MATLAB.

```
cvx_begin
variable D(size(A)) diagonal
minimize(norm(B*D*B' - A,inf))
cvx_end
```

At the conclusion, D is the optimal value.

---

Here is how to do it in YALMIP under MATLAB.

```
D = sdpvar(size(A,1),size(A,1),'diagonal')
optimize([],norm(B*D*B' - A,inf))
value(D) % displays optimal value of D
```

You can optionally specify a specific solver, if you have installed the solver under MATLAB. For instance, you can specify SCS, which is a first order solver, and so can handle larger problems without running out of memory.   `optimize([],norm(B*D*B' - A,inf),sdpsettings('solver','scs'))`

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do this using UnLocbox?

Comment: It looks similar to TFOCS , one of whose authors is the same as the lead author of CVX.  Perhaps it is advantageous for very large problems. But I am not a TFOCS or UnLocbox user, so can;t help you with those.   But I will edit my answer to show you YALMIP code.